# Like button wont add to blog?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, blogs

Hi there I have this blog http://hfbartist-abrushwith.blogspot.com/ on blogger. What ideally I'd like to do is add a facebook like button at the end of each post I do. Either in the body of the post or in the comments box. I don't really understand which option of the code I'm supposed to use, so I tried them all and nothing.

Can anyone let me know if it's possible and how to do it if so?

Thanks muchly

x

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you got this solved. I see a like button at both top and bottom of each blog post with href parameter correctly set. I went to http://hfbartist-abrushwith.blogspot.com/2011/12/brush-with-wow-from-wfto.html